# SELECT one value between two values from the second column

Tags: sql, select

I have one table DS:

```
DS_num  TEXT
DS1     YES
DS1      NO
DS2     YES
DS2      NO
DS3      NO
DS4      NO
DS4     YES
DS5     YES
DS6      NO
DS7     YES
DS7      NO
DS8      NO
.....
```

From table DS I would like to get just DS3, DS6 and DS8. That means I would like to get just DS_num which does not duplicate and have "NO" in TEXT field.

Comment: select * from DS where TEXT="NO" and DS_num IN (select DS_num from DS group by DS_num having count(DS_num)=1)

Comment: What have you tried that we can help to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You could group by `ds_num`, count the number of occurrences and check that the maximum value of `text` (i.e.: the only value in case of a single row) is `no`:

```sql
SELECT   ds_num
FROM     ds
GROUP BY ds_num
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1 AND MAX(text) = 'NO'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DS_num
FROM DS
WHERE TEXT="NO"
  AND DS_num IN
    (SELECT DS_num
     FROM DS
     GROUP BY DS_num
     HAVING count(DS_num)=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   ds_num
FROM     tableA
GROUP BY ds_num
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
```

[Sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77d46/6)